# android sqlite insert 2 values in 2 different columns

Tags: android, sql, insert

Hi I am trying to insert two different values name and comment in my table but I am getting an error. I have a button and when it is clicked I want the values to be stored in the database,I would like to mention that I am quite new to sql and I am just experimenting. Is there any possible way to insert 2 values in 2 different rows ? if so how ? Here is my try. many thanks.

```
   public void onClick(View v)
    {
   mydb.execSQL("insert into test (name) values(?);",new String[]             
   {name.getText().toString()});
   mydb.execSQL("insert into test (comment) values(?);",new String[] 
   {comment.getText().toString()});
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA INSERTED", 3000).show();

   }
   });
```

this is my create table statement.

```
mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name     
varchar,comment varchar);");
```

This seems that is not working though.Any advice guys ?

Comment: Do you mean to insert 2 values in 2 COLUMNS?! If so, you can (and should) do it with only 1 INSERT command

Comment: yes. sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert your values:

```
mydb.execSQL
(
    "INSERT INTO test (name, comment) VALUES (?, ?);",
    new String[]             
    {
        name.getText().toString(),
        comment.getText().toString()
    }
);
```

But:

1. Make sure that mydb is open before executing any query or commands on it.
2. Make sure that your EditTexts are declared and assigned.

Comment: it seems that this way is working but I am getting another error saying that my table has no column named comment. Am i doing something wrong ? thank you sir.I will update my code with the create table statement.

Comment: no, that seems it didnt work. I still get the same error Sir.

Comment: Can you post the logcat, to show us the error? add it to your question.